# convert specified value on array from xml to csv in php

Tags: php, xml, file, csv

i want to convert to csv from xml file only the specified values...

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
<PRODUCT sku="12345" price="129"/>
<PRODUCT sku="12356" price="150"/>
<PRODUCT sku="12367" price="160"/>
<PRODUCT sku="12389" price="190"/>
</file>
```

CSV File.

```
SKU,PRICE
12345,129
12356,150
12367,160
12389,190
```

but i want to get the price only for 12345, 12367 and 12389

This is my start file:

```
 <?php
    $filexml = 'file.xml';
        if (file_exists($filexml)){
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
            $file = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
            $header = array('sku', 'price');
            fputcsv($file, $header, ',', '"');
            foreach ($xml->PRODUCT as $product){
                $item = array();
                $value1 = $product->attributes()->sku;
                $value2 = $product->attributes()->price;

            $item[] = $value1;
        $item[] = $value2;
                fputcsv($file, $item, ',', '"');    
            }
            fclose($file);
        }

    ?>
```

an option can be this, but is returning me Array, maybe is wrong something there.

```
<?php
        $filexml = 'file.xml';
            if (file_exists($filexml)){
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
                $file = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
                $header = array('sku', 'price');
                $customvalue = array('12345', '12367', '12389');
                fputcsv($file, $header, ',', '"');
                foreach ($xml->PRODUCT as $product){
                    $item = array();
                    $value1 = $product->attributes()->sku;
                    $value2 = $product->attributes()->price;

                $item[] = $customvalue;
                $item[] = $value2;
                    fputcsv($file, $item, ',', '"');    
                }
                fclose($file);
            }

        ?>
```

Thanks

Ryan Solution:

```
<?php
            $filexml = 'file.xml';
                if (file_exists($filexml)){
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
                $file = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
                $header = array('sku', 'price');
                    $customvalue = array('12345', '12367', '12389');
                fputcsv($file, $header, ',', '"');
                foreach ($xml->PRODUCT as $product){        
                    if ( in_array($product->attributes()->sku, $customvalue ) ) {
                    $item = array ();
                    $item[] = $product->attributes()->sku;
                    $item[] = $product->attributes()->price;
                    fputcsv($file, $item, ',', '"');    
                    }
                fclose($file);
                }
            ?>
```

but the output is true and good, but i need to remove the unnecessary codes because in large file with about 7000 codes this get a 300mb csv file.

This is the output.

```
12345,129
12345,129,12356,150
12367,160
12389,190
```

in large files im getting this:

```
12345,129
12345,129,123456,150,12367,160
12389,190,123456,150,12367,160,12345,129
12399,200
12399,200,12345,129,12389,160,123456,150
12399,200,12345,129,12389,160,123456,150,12399,200,12345,129,12389,160,123456,150
```

the specified codes in array are first in the right column, but at the end this is creating a big csv file. and result timeout or memory out.

Thanks

Comment: If you can do the two columns one, you should be able to do the single column one too. How did you figure out the two-columns solution? Do you actually understand it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, i will appreciate it and i will try... but im not sure that this will work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Add a check to ensure that you read only the specified rows, and simplify the pulling out of the fields you want, something like this (just the `foreach` loop, the rest while stay the same:

```
    foreach ($xml->PRODUCT as $product){        
    if ( in_array($product->attributes()->sku, $customvalue ) ) {
          $item = array ();
      $item[] = $product->attributes()->sku;
      $item[] = $product->attributes()->price;
      fputcsv($file, $item, ',', '"');    
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your response, is a good solution, but i cannot remove the last codes, i want to get only the specified codes.

Comment: the response is: 
<code>
12345,129
12345,129,12356,150,12367,160
12389,190
</code>

Comment: Maybe update the question to include the expected output. Not sure what output is expected.